# How do I turn off warning from mpif.h with mpif90

Tags: mpi, gfortran, suppress-warnings

I'm trying to compile some code using MPI with mpif90. So I have several subroutines like :

```
subroutine name()    
    include "mpif.h"
    ...
```

and I have a huge number of warnings from this mpif.h like :

```
Warning: Unused parameter 'mpi_win_disp_unit' declared at (1)
mpif.h:243.27:
    Included at main.f90:29:

       INTEGER MPI_WIN_NULL
```

The problem is that I can't see the warnings that come from my actual code.
My current compiler options are :

```
-O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wtabs -ffixed-line-length-132
```

I would like to know if there is a flag that disable warnings from a specific file, or from included files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In C we'd say `#pragma diagnostic ignored -Wunused-parameter` but that particular syntax probably can't be used in gfortran....

Comment: This doesn't answer the general problem, but in your case could you `use mpi` instead of `include "mpif.h"`?

Comment: Yes I can in my code, but the statement `include "mpif.h"` is used in some pieces of code that are not mine. I'm not sure I am allowed to modify it. Is there a benefit to do such a change ?

Comment: `use mpi` provides type checking for some MPI function arguments and also is more F90-ish.